# Como podria recibir los datos para iniciar sesion de react a Laravel???En la imagen se muestra el codigo que ocupo para mandar los datos a laravel

Tags: laravel, reactjs

[image: En este codigo mando los datos del correo y contraseña que se insertan en el formulario como le hago para recibir estos datos en Laravel??*Me ayudarian para saber como quedaria el metodo de login en el controlador de laravel *]
En este codigo mando los datos del correo y contraseña que se insertan en el formulario como le hago para recibir estos datos en Laravel??*Me ayudarian para saber como quedaria el metodo de login en el controlador de laravel

Comment: ajdjuntar codigo como texto y no imagen

Comment: Voto por cerrar la pregunta por que, según lo mencionado en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880, poner fotos de código no es buena idea. Además, el OP aun no respondió a la solicitud de cambiar esto en su pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo envio desde mi pagina de login el email y el password asi...

```
const data = {
    email,
    password,
};

try{
    const response = await api.post('api/auth/login', data);
```

la ruta es esta

```
Route::post('auth/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

y el controller está asi

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
   $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

   if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
      return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
   }

   return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

el controller retorna un token cuando el usuario esta autorizado, ese token lo almaceno en el navegador

```
localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.access_token);
history.push('/dashboard');
```

Espero te de una luz en tu problema.